# JQuery handler can't access data after Ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, each

I made a Javascript object for updating and handling data using $.ajax({}) and external php scripts. The table element returned from the object when the object is called contains a number of hidden tr's (using the class "hidden", which is set to display:none).

Here is the display function inside the object:

```
this.displayData = function(location_div) {
    var location_div = location_div;
    $.ajax({
            url:"display_data.php",
            type: "POST", 
            success:function(response){ 
                $(location_div).html(response);
                },
            error:function(response){alert("Error Displaying Problems." + response)},
        });
    };
```

which displays:

```
<div id="location_div">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="hidden"></tr>
            <tr class="hidden"></tr>
            <tr class="hidden"></tr>
            <tr class="hidden"></tr>
        </tbody>
    <table>
</div>
```

(note: "#location_div" is the element passed to "displayData(location_div)")

The problem I'm having is when the JQuery tries to access the returned data. I have a function that looks for all of the tr's, pushes each to an array, and then fades each one in one-by-one.

```
var elements_array = new Array();
$("#location_div table tbody").children().each(function() {
    elements_array.push(this);
});
//function for fading in each element in the array
fadeAllIn(elements_array);
```

As I understand it, elements that are Ajax-loaded are not part of the DOM, and so one needs to use a JQuery function such as $(element).on(); or $(element).live(); However, nothing I have tried has worked. The table is being loaded, but JQuery can't seem to select each tr using .each() because the table is Ajax-loaded.

Does anyone know the solution/workaround for this? Is there a better solution than using JQuery to fade in each tr in the table?

Comment: Can you make an [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) with all you code. I want to see what's declaring what and when.

Comment: Where are you calling this method.. Looks like you are calling the method before the Data is populated as ``Ajax is Asyn`

Comment: What if you were to create a function for your "array pusher" and then call that as a success callback from your ajax function? 
Edit: Just saw that @face's answer essentially does this.

Comment: Sorry, that last pastebin had an error in the syntax, here's the pastebin with the right syntax: http://pastebin.com/LjtvQb31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to bind your events/animations after the dynamic data has been loaded.

```
this.displayData = function(location_div) {
var location_div = location_div;
$.ajax({
        url:"display_data.php",
        type: "POST", 
        success:function(response){ 
            $(location_div).html(response);
            bind_events();                
        },
        error:function(response){alert("Error Displaying Problems." + response)},
    });
};

var bind_events = function(){
    var elements_array = new Array();
            $("#location_div table tbody").children().each(function() {
                 elements_array.push(this);
            });
            fadeAllIn(elements_array);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I'm trying to keep the code that creates the array and fades elements in outside of the object, that way I can keep the object as general as possible and reuse it for different purposes if I need to. Is there a way to do it without having the array code and fade in code inside the displayData function?

Comment: Oh! I have put that in a comment. Just store the array code and fade in code part in a separate function and call this function in here. I will try and update my example for more clarity

Comment: Ah, gotcha, sorry, didn't see the code section in your answer. Apologies! So if I put the array/fade in code in a function, will I be able to call that function from outside the object? Should I place that function after the DisplayData() function, or can I place it outside the object and still be able to call it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you need to use delegation via the .on method. What you need to do to use javascript/jquery to fade the elements is attach the event handler to an element that is on the page when the page loads.

eg:

```
$("location_div").on("click", "table tbody", function() { [function] });
```

or something similar where "click" is your event.

Comment: I realize that, I was just trying to illustrate event delegation as simply as possible. I think the issue is that he is binding to a selector that does not fully exist in the DOM yet.

Comment: That is true, but it doesn't look like OP is binding anything, just selecting some elements to push into an array. See @face's answer.